# How To Edit User Without Password Using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm still a beginner with Rails and have searched for an answer for awhile. I'm using Devise for authentication in my app and want users to be able to update their account information without using the current password. I have already looked at the Devise documentation on  [allowing users to edit their account without providing a password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password).

In doing so I will encounter a couple errors. Regardless of which controller setup (provided by the documentation) I use when submitting account updates, I get this:

```
    Can't mass-assign protected attributes: current_password
```

So, I go to my User model and add :current_password to attr_accessible. Then when submitting updates, I'll see this:

```
    unknown attribute: current_password
```

So, I'm stuck. I can't figure out what the deal is. I'm 90% sure I have routes.rb set up correctly (again, following the documentation). I'm thinking that if I didn't, these error messages wouldn't even appear.

Comment: Could you show us your model ? Are you using mongoid or ActiveRecord ?

Comment: Try and add the following `attr_accessor :current_password`

Comment: @GeraudMathe I'm using ActiveRecord.

Comment: Adding 'attr_accessor :current_password' yields the same 'Can't mass-assign protected attributes: current_password' error

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `<%= f.input :current_password %>` from the `app/views/device/registrations/edit.html.erb`

Comment: Doesn't this prevent the user from ever editing their password? I think he wants to give them the choice.

Comment: To edit the password the `:password` field will be available.

Comment: Removing the current password field follows through without error but still will require the password field to be filled.

Comment: did you follow he steps to skip empty password. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Comment: Yes, this will go through but will then give a validation error. Saying that the password field can't be left blank.

Comment: I figured out my issue. In the user model, I had overridden the default Devise validations for the email and password, and wrote out the presence validations manually along with other necessary attributes. Removing email and password from the manual validations, and adding back the Devise validations call into the user model seems to have fixed the issue, for now.